# How to check current date is greater then or equal to stored in data base date and time in C#

Tags: c#

'Following is the code, I want to be check stored in database date and time if greater or equal then current date and time, if current date is greater then stored date then how to compare Time in this check

```
  DateTime sysDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
  int sysMinute = DateTime.Now.Minute;
  int sysHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
  DateTime scheduledDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Scheduled_Start_Date.ToString()).Date;
  int scheduledMinute = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Scheduled_Start_Time.ToString()).Minute;
  int scheduledHour = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Scheduled_Start_Time.ToString()).Hour;
  if (sysDate >= scheduledDate && sysMinute >= scheduledMinute && sysHour >= scheduledHour)
  {
    var currency = GetEventCurrency(evDB.EventID);
    ev.PriceRange = currency.GetFormattedAmount(item.ScheduledPrice.ToString());
    isScheduledPrice = true;
  }
```

Comment: You can compare DateTimes directly e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_greaterthanorequal?view=net-6.0.  Then your check is just `DateTime.Now >= scheduledTime` or similar.  (I would recommend being careful of DateTime.Now due to daylight savings - consider using DateTime.UtcNow.  However, this depends on your precise use case.)

Comment: This check will execute when ever form load and function execute, at ftrst time date & time will matches it moves into if block so in next day when this check runs obviously date is greater but the time will differ then it will not move into if block. So how can i over come this issue

Comment: @DaniyalBaig: Is `02/02/2022 17:00` greater than `01/01/2022 18:00`? Yes. Is `17` greater than `18`? No. Your comparison is wrong. If `DateTime.Now` happens to be just before midnight, _no_ datetime value could be "greater" than it, no matter how many days/months/years it may be in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When getting system datetime with DateTime.Now you have to be aware that several calls may produce incoherent results. This is specially important on the change of the minute, hour or even day.
Do just one call and operate with that result.
In your question is not necessary to segregate DateTime components.

```
DateTime sysDate = DateTime.Now;
        
DateTime scheduledDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Scheduled_Start_Date.ToString()).Date;
DateTime scheduledTime = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Scheduled_Start_Time.ToString()).Time;
DateTime scheduledDateTime = scheduledDate + scheduledTime;
```

Once scheduled datetime is in C# format you can just compare them:

```
if (sysDate >= scheduledDateTime)
{
    var currency = GetEventCurrency(evDB.EventID);
    ev.PriceRange = currency.GetFormattedAmount(item.ScheduledPrice.ToString());
    isScheduledPrice = true;
}
```

Datetimes in C# are stored in [ticks (100 ns) from 00:00:00 of January 1st of year 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0#datetime-values-and-their-string-representations) up to the expressed date and time.
Comparison thus is easy as those are just scalars (internally).